# Printing thumbnails using simpleXML parse - how to return all?

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I have looked for this answer to this question on here but I can't seem to find anything which is relevant to this particular issue.

I am currently using simpleXML to parse an RSS feed, in order to return thumbnail images by going through the nodes to parse "media:thumbnail". I have managed to do this and return all thumbnail URLs, so I know that I am getting to the right content, like so:

```
<?php 

$url = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
$media = $item->children('media', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
foreach($media->thumbnail as $thumb) {
   echo $thumb->attributes()->url;
}
}

?>
```

This echos all the image urls. But when I store this in to a variable and try to echo this later as the img src, it only returns one image, rather than all:

```
<?php 

$url = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
$media = $item->children('media', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
foreach($media->thumbnail as $thumb) {
   $image = $thumb->attributes()->url;
}
}
?>

<div><img src = <?php echo $image; ?> /></div>
```

How can I echo all of the URLs in to individual images? Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're getting and expecting multiple image urls, might as well store them inside an array:

```
$images_container = array();
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $media = $item->children('media', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    foreach($media->thumbnail as $thumb) {
       $image = $thumb->attributes()->url;
       $images_container[] = (string) $image;
    }
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($images_container, 1), '<pre>';
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sgZzP2)

Now of course, if you want to process those array of string image urls, then just use and process the container:

```
<?php foreach($images_container as $url): ?>
    <div><img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="" /></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[Pictures](http://codepad.viper-7.com/T95QuG)

Comment: Thanks. This prints the array, and I understand why it makes sense to store it, but I still can't seem to print the images themselves? I tried:              
<img src = <?php echo print_r($images_container, 1); ?> />
but this doesn't work either

Comment: @NickR93 kindly check out the second link inside my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try `xpath`.

```
$url = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace( 'media', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' );
// get only thumbnails of specified width
$xpath = $xml->xpath( '//media:thumbnail[@url and @width=144]' );

/**
 * The above xpath will get only thumbnails of width 144
 */

foreach( $xpath as $node ) {
    echo '<div><img src="' . $node['url'] . '" /></div>';
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Quick question...there are two media:thumbnails within each item, they are the same image but different sizes. Is there any way to specify which one I want each time?